# Windows batch: using goto in a loop

Tags: batch-file

The following code runs a continuous loop, which increments the variable `counter`. When counter reaches 10, it should call the `set_varibles` routine, and then continue in the loop from the place `set_variables` was called. However, the `goto` does not work. What is wrong, and is there a better solution? Thanks

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

:set_variables
SET t=ooo

:my_loop
set /a counter=0
for /L %%n in (1,0,10) do (
   echo !counter!
   set /a counter=counter+1
   if !counter! equ 10 (
      echo now TEN
      goto set_variables
   )
)
@echo on
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: if you want to call, why don't you use `call`? (see `call /?`)

Comment: I don't want to call another batch file - only the labelled routine within the same batch file. Can I use CALL for that? Does not seem to work?

Comment: `call /?` says: `CALL :label arguments` (don't forget the colon for labels). Works fine (except if you disable extensions). I use it regulary.

Answer (score 3):

[CALL a subroutine (:label)](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html)

> The following code runs a continuous loop, which increments the
>   variable `counter`. When `counter` reaches `10`, it should call the
>   `set_varibles` routine, and then continue in the loop from the place
>   `set_variables` was called.

Exactly as proposed: `echo now TEN` and `call :set_variables` **every tenth pass** the **endless** loop.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

call :set_variables

:my_loop
set /a counter=0
for /L %%n in (1,0,10) do (
   echo !counter!
   set /a counter=counter+1
   set /a auxcounter=counter%%10
   if !auxcounter! equ 0 (
      echo now TEN
      call :set_variables
   )
)
@echo on
ENDLOCAL
@goto :eof

:set_variables
SET t=ooo
@goto :eof
```

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is not the `goto` command, but the `for /l`

While usually a `goto` command will cancel any block of code (code in parenthesis), `for /l` loops are a different beast. There are only two ways to leave a running `for /l`: an `exit` command (not `exit /b` unless the code is running in a command line context), or if the counter is greater than the end value.

Than means that the `goto` can not go out of the loop. It will cancel the execution of the code inside the `do` clause, but the loop will not be finished until the end value is reached, and your `for` loop

```
               start  step   end 
for /L %%n in (    1,    0,   10 ) do  ...
```

has a step value of 0 making it impossible to reach the end value.

The equivalent to your posted code could be

```dos
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

:set_variables
    SET t=ooo

:my_loop
    for /L %%n in (0,1,9) do (
       echo %%n
       set /a counter=%%n+1
       rem ....
    )
    echo now TEN
    goto set_variables
```

Comment: An `exit /B` command can cancel a `for /L` loop if the Batch file is being executed in a nested `cmd.exe /C` instance; this trick allows to assemble a "while" loop in Batch! Complete details at [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3487).

Comment: @Aacini, answer updated. I was thinking in the contents of the batch file and I forget this case. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this what you want:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

:set_variables

:my_loop
for /L %%n in (1,1,10) do (
   echo %%n
   if %%n equ 10 (
      echo now TEN
      SET t=ooo
   )
)
goto my_loop

@echo on
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: no, I want to re-run the routine which is called periodically  within the loop. Everytime the counter reaches a certain value, the routine must be called and the counter variable reset.

Answer (score 0):

Using GOTO within parenthesis - including FOR and IF commands - will break their context.

Some things look odd in your script. Why have a continuous loop and then restart it when a counter reaches 10? Why not use "in (1,1,10)" like in Monacraft's answer?

Why does this tweaked version not do what you want?

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set /a outer_counter=0

:set_variables
echo start of set_variables
SET t=ooo

:my_loop
set /a counter=0
for /L %%n in (1,1,10) do (
   echo !counter!
   set /a counter=counter+1
   set /a outer_counter=outer_counter+1
   if !counter! equ 10 (
     echo now TEN
   )
)

if !outer_counter! geq 100 goto after_loop
goto set_variables


:after_loop
echo FINISHED
@echo on
ENDLOCAL
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

I hate when additional specifications are placed in *comments* instead of the question description, but this comment appeared below Monacraft's answer:

> I want to re-run the routine which is called periodically within the loop.
>   Everytime the counter reaches a certain value, the routine must be called
>   and the counter variable reset.

So I think that the solution to *all* OP's requests is this:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

call :set_variables

:my_loop
for /L %%n in (1,0,10) do (
   echo !counter!
   set /a counter=counter+1
   if !counter! equ 10 (
      echo now TEN
      call :set_variables
   )
)

No matter what is placed here, because a *continuous loop* NEVER ENDS!
@echo on
ENDLOCAL


:set_variables
SET t=ooo
set /a counter=0
exit /B
```

Comment: Did you saw my answer? Solve it your problem?